# A confusion about the final answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is let **A** be a 2*2 matrix. If 5+3i is an Eigenvalue of **A**, then the det(**A**) is?
Now I know that eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix.
Now as all complex roots occur in pairs, I also know that the other eigenvalue is 5-3i.
So being a 2*2 matrix the characteristic polynomial is a maximum of the power 2.
So, (x-(5+3i))(x-(5-3i)) would be the characteristic polynomial.
Expanding it I'm getting the answer as x^2-10x+34
now I know b is the trace of **A** and c is the det(A) but the options are
4,8,16 or cannot be determined from the given information.
Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is the matrix a *real* matrix? Otherwise the `all complex roots occur in pairs` part doesn't hold.

Comment: yes, it is a real matrix

Comment: Assuming it is a real matrix, the correct result is $34$ indeed. Maybe the problem had a typo, or maybe something got lost in transcribing.

Comment: yeah, must be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are real (this will happen if $A$ is a real matrix for example), then the eigenvalues will occur in conjugate pairs. Then the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. So 
$$
\det A = (5+3i)(5-3i)=25+9=34.
$$

Comment: yes, I got to that part. Even I am getting the answer as 34 but the options are 4,8,16 or cannot be determined.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, if nowhere in the original text it is mentioned that all entries of the matrix are real, then you cannot assume that the other eigenvalue is $5-3i$ and thus based upon your given info, I would pick answer "cannot be determined". Otherwise, it has to be 34

Comment: yeah, I know. must be a typing mistake I suppose then. Anyway, thank you for your comment